# Moving items using intemized overlay

Tags: android

I'm interested in a way to implement moving objects in a Google maps application. So far, I've done so by creating new OverlayItems and discarding the old ones, than doing populate to update the map. This, however, seems impractical and inefficient to me.

The problem I encounter is that the latitude and longitude attributes of `GeoPoint` are final, so I cannot change them once the `GeoPoint` is created.

Any suggestions on how to solve (or work around) this? Why are these attributes final?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating and destroying objects in ItemizedOverlay is expensive, an alternative would be to extend the [Overlay](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/Overlay.html) class and perform your own [draw()](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/Overlay.html#draw%28android.graphics.Canvas,%20com.google.android.maps.MapView,%20boolean%29) where you don't need to use GeoPoint and thus can update the lat/lon values yourself.

BTW: you do perform [populate()](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/ItemizedOverlay.html#populate%28%29) only once for each set, and not for each item in the set?

Comment: That's Yes, I populate once for each set. Thanks for the tip, sounds sound!